# session timeout is not working for webpart in MS sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

in web.config

This settings is there.

I want to kill the session:
1. if user is iddle for 20 min.
2. if user close the browser without logout then i want to kill the session after 20 min.

Comment: web.config:
<sessionState mode="InProc"      stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"            sqlConnectionString="data source=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes"            cookieless="false" timeout="20"  />

Answer (score -1):

Try
In web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="20"  />
```

Comment: it is there in web.config